# Can't install laravel using composer

Tags: php, composer-php

When I run the following command in the command prompt I get the following error

> command "composer global require laravel/installer"
>
> error "In CurlDownloader.php line 365:
>
> curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8465 after 2044 ms: Connection refused"

I have tried  the following solutions :

- running Composer without  SSL/TLS protection disabled but I got the same error
- downloading the packages on github and then use it to develop laravel but that did not work either
- turning off windows firewall
- changing directories and even changing the command prompt to the xampp shell !

I mostly undid the changes after finding out that they aren't effective
just need a way to Install laravel and become a software developer ;)

"composer diagnose " result :

## composer diagnose

You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK git version 2.41.0
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 7 while downloading http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8465 after 2023 ms: Connection refused
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8465 after 2018 ms: Connection refused
Composer is configured to disable SSL/TLS protection. This will leave remote HTTPS requests vulnerable to Man-In-The-Middle attacks.
Checking HTTP proxy: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 7 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8465 after 2035 ms: Connection refused
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 7 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8465 after 2045 ms: Connection refused
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: Warning: Accessing getcomposer.org over http which is an insecure protocol.
FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 7 while downloading http://getcomposer.org/versions: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8465 after 2044 ms: Connection refused
Composer version: 2.6-dev+bbea3e5284fd859373c292c7f696f9647f9a59ef
PHP version: 8.2.4
PHP binary path: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
cURL version: 7.85.0 libz 1.2.12 ssl OpenSSL/3.0.8
zip: extension not loaded, unzip not available, 7-Zip not available

Comment: Can you try to run the command `composer diagnose` and share the outcome ?

Comment: hey ;)  thanks for your help I shared a screenshot of the result in the post plz check it out !

Comment: What happens if you visit https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json in your browser? What does `dig repo.packagist.org` show?

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, provide the text. Reason: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). And check your network configuration https://repo.packagist.org resolves to 127.0.0.1 port 8465. (same for https://api.github.com .)

Comment: Maybe you should disable your antivirüs and / or use an another DNS.